# Antlr4 C++ visit ambiguous branch

Tags: c++, antlr4, grammar, visitor-pattern

So let's say I have a rule like this:

```
rule : '(' rule ')' | '!' rule '!';
```

Now in my runtime I have this method:

```
antlrcpp::Any runtimeVisitor::visitRule(tinycParser::RuleContext *ctx) { 
     ...
}
```

How can I check whether I am in the fist or in the second case? Might something like this works?

```
if(ctx->rule(0)) visitRule(ctx->rule(0))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can label your alternatives like this:

```
rule
    : '(' rule ')' #ParenthesizedRule
    | '!' rule '!' #ExclamationMarkRule
    | ...
    ;
```

Then you can define specific visitor methods for each alternative (i.e. `visitParenthesizedRule`, `visitExclamationMarkRule` etc.) instead of `visitRule`.

If you don't want to add anything to your grammar, you can also just check whether the first child of the rule is an opening parenthesis or an exclamation mark:

```
if (ctx.children[0].getText() == "(") {
    ...
} else if (ctx.children[0].getText() == "!") {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

Comment: thank you very very much, can you please post a snipped of the second option? thank you again